# How can I check source code of a module in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

For example, I want to check the source code of a python library, directly in the notebook, is there a way to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Type the fully qualified function name, then type `??`.

Comment: This is something really Cool!

Comment: @Chinny84, is there a way to configure the notebook to use an external editor? I want to use a bigger window to read the code. By default, it seems the external widow is displayed in the browser, and therefor there is no syntax coloring, which is bad.

Comment: Typing e.g. `numpy.random.rand` gives me the docstring! what do you mean exactly by a full qualified function name? Trying `cv2.resize??` also doesn't work. Could the reason be that these function are not actually written in pure Python?

Comment: I typed this:  `sklearn.metrics.classification_report??` .. then what to do?

Comment: `from sklearn.metrics import classification_report` and then `classification_report??` + Shift Enter

Comment: I want to see the actual source code of count object in itertools.count. Doing `itertools.count??` doesn't help much.

Comment: at least in JupyterLab, the "Show Contextual Help" tab is where the information is shown.  took me a minute to find...

Answer (score 11):

You can use inspect module (which is built in) - for example you can see the tree module below from scikit-learn.

```
import inspect
from sklearn import tree
inspect.getsourcelines(tree.tree)
```

Comment: `inspect.getsource(tree.tree)` would print it like a file.