# How can I go to a function's definition in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

How can i go to a function definition in Jupyter?

I want something like Visual studio's f12, or eclipse's and PyCharm's ctrl+click.

I find it hard to believe this does not exist, yet couldn't find it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check source code of a module in Jupyter notebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40941476/how-can-i-check-source-code-of-a-module-in-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: you can also open your Jupyter notebook (*.ipynb) in Visual Studio code if you use that. It has a Jupyter extension which comes pre-installed with the Python extension which has all the suggestion features

Answer (score 17):

I'm not aware of such feature that will work for all kernels.

If you are using a Python kernel and have ipython installed you can use inspection functions:

> - `%pdoc <object>`: Print (or run through a pager if too long) the docstring for an object. If the given object is a class, it will print
>     both the class and theconstructor docstrings.
> - `%pdef <object>`: Print the call signature for any callable object. If    the object is a class, print the constructor information.
> - `%psource <object>`: Print (or run through a pager if too long) the source code    for an object.
> - `%pfile <object>`: Show the entire source file where an object was defined via a pager, opening it at the line where the object
>     definition begins.
> - `%who/%whos`: These functions give information about identifiers you have defined interactively (not things you loaded or defined in
>     your configuration files). %who just prints a list of identifiers and
>     %whos prints a table with some basic details about each identifier.
>
> Typing `??word` or `word??` gives access to the full information,
>   including the source code where possible. Long strings are not
>   snipped.

#### Usage Example

```
In [4]: pd.DataFrame?

In [5]: pd.DataFrame??

In [6]: %pdef pd.Dataframe
Object `pd.Dataframe` not found.

In [7]: %pdef pd.DataFrame
Class constructor information:
 pd.DataFrame(data=None, index=None, columns=None, dtype=None, copy=False)

In [8]: %pdoc pd.DataFrame

In [9]: %pfile pd.DataFrame
```

#### Resources

[Dynamic object information](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#dynamic-object-information)

Answer (score 6):

If you can upgrade to JupyterLab, you could install [jupyterlab-go-to-definition](https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-go-to-definition) extension with:

```
jupyter labextension install @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition
```

It supports R and Python and allows to jump to definitions with alt-click (where alt can be changed to another key modifier in the settings). For more usage details see the linked GitHub repository (above).

On the technical side, there are two ways to get the location of definitions in a notebook: static analysis and inspection in the kernel. If you cannot upgrade to JupyterLab yet, you could try to re-implement either of those for jupyter-notebook.

- The kernel inspections may seem easier to implement because they do not depend on the code editor used, but have to be written for each language separately. [Here](https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-go-to-definition/blob/27923a90dd7567cddc26841d12df3ad068878183/src/languages/python.ts#L250) is an example for Python
- static analysis can be done via external tool but those will be problematic due to the nature of the notebook (being composed of multiple cells, unlike normal source code files); the approach used in the extension above is to analyze the tokens of CodeMirror editor, iterating over cells, starting from the cell with the symbol usage (where the user alt-clicked on a variable). Here is an example of [implementation](https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-go-to-definition/blob/27923a90dd7567cddc26841d12df3ad068878183/src/jumpers/jumper.ts#L97) for such iteration.

Disclaimer: I am the author of this extension.

Edit: For an implementation which allows the same for **any** language (provided that you install a language server for this language), see: [jupyterlab-lsp](https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp) (with many other features too!). The difference is that it only uses static analysis for now (the kernel-based position retrieval is not implemented just yet).

Comment: Hi,where should I run this command:  jupyter labextension install @krassowski/jupyterlab_go_to_definition? In the jupyter notebook or in the linux environment, under some folder?

Comment: Is this extension only for jupyter notebook? or for jupyter lab?

Comment: Only for jupyter lab, but its successor, [jupyterlab-lsp](https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp) uses jupyter-lsp underneath which in principle could be ported for jupyter notebook. Not that it matters since with upcoming JupyterLab 3.0 release the notebook interface will be incorporated into JupyterLab (you will get the same experience after enabling notebook mode)

Answer (score 2):

I used below to return call signature of function, [taken from above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53457694/5625975)

```
np.matmul??
```

If you have the function typed out, you can use [keyboard combination](https://towardsdatascience.com/jypyter-notebook-shortcuts-bf0101a98330) 'Shift+Tab' + 'Shift+Tab' to get tool tip in notebook when in edit mode, as shown below.

[image: Jupyter Notebook Tooltip]

Comment: This does not answer the question. I was not looking for tool tips, but was looking to jump to the function. This is also why the above answer is not accepted.

Comment: oh well, this helps get the function definition